# Creating id for Contact Form 7 checkbox options

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I am curious if I can give id to Contact Form 7 checkbox select options.

Currently I have the following checkbox:

> [checkbox days "Monday" "Tuesday" "Wednesday" "Thursday" "Friday"]

In html it looks like this: `<input type="checkbox" name="days[]" value="Monday">`

Can I add an ID to it? I am asking because I have other checkboxes and the values are not so simple, they are multiple words like: value="After 4pm" and I don't like that from a programming perspective. So I want to either change the value fo the input or add an ID to it.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: No You cannot, it is badly coded.

Answer (score -1):

You can just wrap the checkbox with a div. Just like this

```
<div id="days">
   [checkbox days "Monday" "Tuesday" "Wednesday" "Thursday" "Friday"]
</div>
```

Hope this helps. :)